# Authentication failed due to an invalid token

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'm looking in the logs in the azure portal. 
and i'm getting allot of errors with the text - Authentication failed due to an invalid token with no extra data.

Anyone can explain how it happen and how to prevent that.
I use a custom login provider implemented like example i saw in the azure documentation.

thanks

attached is the logs I get

[image: Logs of invalid token]

Comment: Please share some example logs. Be sure to clean any sensitive data out first.

Comment: Are you seeing any failures on your clients? Or are they just in the logs?

Comment: Hard to tell. this is a new app and our clients are students. we didn't get any feedback on that issue.

Comment: This is why client side telemetry is important. Azure has a service called App Service and other services like New Relic could help with that too. :) It's possible that your app lets people make requests when they aren't authenticated, but of course you block them so they have to authenticate before they get requests. It's hard to say this is an issue unless you get some additional information that your customers are impacted.